# Filter, which does not have the Baire property

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, filters, baire-category

I do not understand the following proof of the following theorem. It is part of Theorem 4.1.2 (Talagrand theorem) in the book Tomek Bartoszyński and Haim Judah: *Set theory. On the structure of the real line.*

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a filter on $\omega$ which contains the cofinite filter.

(1) For every partition of $\omega$ into finite sets $I_n$, there exists $X\in\mathcal{F}$ s.t. $X\cap I_n=\emptyset$ for infinitely many $n\in\omega$.

(2)$\mathcal{F}$ does not have the Baire property.

Then (1) implies (2)

Proof: Let $F=\cup_{n\in\omega}F_n$ be any meager set of type $F_\sigma$. Then there exists $x_F\in 2^\omega$ and a strictly increasing function  $f_F$ s.t

$F\subseteq \{x\in 2^\omega:\forall^\infty n \exists j\in[f_F(n),f_F(n+1))x(j)\not=x_F(j)\}$

Let $I_n=[f_F(n),f_F(n+1))$ for $n\in\omega$. Find $X\in\mathcal{F}$ s.t. $X\cap I_n=\emptyset$ for infinitely many $n\in\omega$. Define $Y\in 2^\omega$ as follows:
$Y|I_n=X|I_n$, if $X\cap I_n=\emptyset$ and $Y|I_n=x_F|I_n$ if $X\cap I_n\not=\emptyset$. Then $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\notin\mathcal{F}$, which is a contradiction.

q.e.d.

Why does the author starts with a meager set of type $F_\sigma$ and not with a filter, which has the Baire property?

Comment: What Baire property are we talking about here. Just being Baire (i.e. not being a union of countably many nowhere dense sets), or something else?

Comment: Or, $A$ has the property of Baire iff there is some open set $U$ such that $A \Delta U$ is meagre?

Comment: The filter to be considered will be identified by a subset of $2^\omega$. And concerning the definition of B.P., we used the second one.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Corrected

Comment: What is the origin of this problem. (I'd say including source of the problem is useful in general.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak It is from the book "Set Theory: On the Structure of the Real Line" by Bartoszynski,

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have added the information about the book into your post. Mentioning the source is useful for several reasons. People reading your question who are interested in additional details may consult the book if they have it. (This might also help potential answerers.) And if somebody has problems with Theorem 4.1.2 in the same book, this makes easier for them to find your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the argument is stated *very* tersely. The author is assuming that the filter $\mathscr{F}$ satisfies (1) and showing that it is not contained in any meagre $F_\sigma$. Let me expand the argument a bit.

Let $F=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}F_n$, where each $F_n$ is closed and nowhere dense in $2^\omega$. For $n\in\omega$ let $$G_n=2^\omega\setminus\bigcup_{k\le n}F_n\;,$$ and let $$G=\bigcap_{n\in\omega}G_n=2^\omega\setminus F\;.$$

For $x\in 2^{<\omega}$ let

$$B(x)=\{y\in 2^\omega:y\upharpoonright\operatorname{dom}x=x\}\;.$$

Each $G_n$ is dense and open in $2^\omega$, so we can recursively construct a strictly increasing $f:\omega\to\omega$ such that for each $n\in\omega$ and each $x\in 2^{f(n)}$ there is a $y\in 2^{f(n+1)}$ such that $y\cap f(n)=x$, and $B(y)\subseteq G_n$. For $n\in\omega$ let $I_n=[f(n),f(n+1))$, and let $X\in\mathscr{F}$ be such that $X\cap I_n=\varnothing$ for infinitely many $n\in\omega$.

Recursively construct $y_n\in 2^{f(n)}$ as follows.

- If $X\cap I_n\ne\varnothing$, let $y_{n+1}=y_n\cup(X\cap I_n)$.
- If $X\cap I_n=\varnothing$, choose $y_{n+1}\in 2^{f(n+1)}$ such that $y_n=y_{n+1}\cap f(n)$, and $B(y_{n+1})\subseteq G_n$.

Let

$$Y=\bigcup_{n\in\omega}y_n\in 2^\omega\;.$$

Clearly $X\subseteq Y$, so $Y\in\mathscr{F}$. Moreover, $Y\cap f(n)=y_n$ for each $n\in\omega$.

If $X\cap I_n=\varnothing$, then $Y\in B\big(Y\cap f(n+1)\big)=B(y_{n+1})\subseteq G_n$. There are infinitely many such $n\in\omega$, and the sequence $\langle G_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ is decreasing, so $Y\in G$. Thus, $\mathscr{F}\cap G\ne\varnothing$, so $\mathscr{F}\nsubseteq F$, and hence $\mathscr{F}$ is not meagre in $2^\omega$.

Finally, a filter on $\omega$ with the Baire property must be meagre in $2^\omega$, so $\mathscr{F}$ cannot have the Baire property.

**Added:** It occurs to me that it might be a good idea to prove that last observation.

Suppose that $\mathscr{F}$ is a non-meagre filter with the Baire property; then there are a non-empty open set $U$ and a meagre set $A$ such that $U\mathrel{\triangle}\mathscr{F}=A$. Then $U\setminus\mathscr{F}\subseteq A$, so there is a $y\in 2^{<\omega}$ such that $\varnothing\ne B(y)\setminus\mathscr{F}\subseteq A$. $B(y)$ is homeomorphic to $2^\omega$, and $A\cap B(y)$ is meagre in $B(y)$, so $\mathscr{F}$ contains a dense $G_\delta$ subset $H$ of $B(y)$.

Let $n=\operatorname{dom}y$, and define

$$h:B(y)\to B(y):z\mapsto y\cup\{k\ge n:k\notin z\}\;;$$

then $h$ is an autohomeomorphism of $B(y)$, so $h[H]\subseteq h[\mathscr{F}]$ is a dense $G_\delta$ subset of $B(y)$, and therefore so is $H\cap h[H]\subseteq\mathscr{F}\cap h[\mathscr{F}]$. Now $h$ is an involution, so $z\in\mathscr{F}\cap h[\mathscr{F}]$ iff $z\in\mathscr{F}$ and $h(z)\in\mathscr{F}$, in which case $z\cap h(z)\in\mathscr{F}$. But $z\cap h(z)=y\notin\mathscr{F}$, since $\mathscr{F}$ contains the cofinite filter. Thus, $\mathscr{F}$ cannot both be non-meagre and have the Baire property.

Comment: I was wondering about the last part: why is it true that a filter on $\omega$ with the Baire property (i.e. almost open) must be meagre? I was looking in the book this came from (which did prove the existence of the $y_F$ and $f_F$ in a separate theorem) and the author did not mention it near this theorem. That was the part that had me confused.

Comment: @Henno: You caught me just as I was adding that bit, having realized that it wasn’t quite so easy to see (for most of us, anyway!) as Talagrand implies in the paper in which he proved this result.

Comment: I think that I saw it mentioned that Sierpiński showed this first.

Comment: @Henno: It’s possible; this result is just part of a result by Talagrand, Theorem $21$ in [this paper](https://eudml.org/doc/218303), which is where I saw it.

Comment: Only the last observation was due to Sierpiński, IIRC. The whole theorem is indeed credited to Talagrand in the book (Set theory, structure of the real line).

Comment: Why can you construct such a function $f$? It's not clear to me.

Comment: @peer: $G_n$ is dense, so if $x\in 2^{f(n)}$, $B(x)\cap G_n\ne\varnothing$. Pick $y_x\in B(x)\cap G_n$; $G_n$ is open, so there is an $m_x>f(n)$ such that $B(y_x\upharpoonright m_x)\subseteq G_n$. Let $f(n+1)=\max_{x\in 2^{f(n)}}m_x$; then for each $x\in 2^{f(n)}$, $y_x\upharpoonright f(n+1)$ has the desired properties.

Comment: By the way, i assume you are using the standard topology on $2^\omega$. Is $2^\omega$ with this topology polish?

Comment: @peer: Yes: it's a Cantor set.